# Compose for desktop Window and Dialog onCloseOperation not working

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on a desktop application using Compose for desktop, I want to open a new window when I click on a row of a table, the window opens correctly but it does not close when I click the X button

These are the 2 versions of the window that I have made, one using a Dialog so that no other action can be done while the window is open

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Detail(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Window(
        state = WindowState(WindowPlacement.Maximized),
        resizable = false,
        onCloseRequest = { },
        visible = true
    ) {
        
    }
}

@Composable
fun Detail2(
    onCloseRequest: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Dialog(
        onCloseRequest = { onCloseRequest() },
        content = { content() }
    )
}
```